# Почему так выводит?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть некий Dataframe:

```
print(data.values)
```

Выводит:

```
[   nan   0.8635   0.8674   0.86925  0.86155  0.851675 0.8503   0.855425
 0.859525 0.87385  0.90065 ]
```

Однако когда пишу:

```
print(data.iloc[-1])
```

Выводит:

```
0.9006499999999997
```

А нужно 0.90065. В чем проблема? Как выводить числа точь в точь как в data.values?

Comment: Оберни твой `data.iloc[-1]` в `round()` https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/okruglenie.html
Должно выйти что то вроде `print(round(data.iloc[-1], 5))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вопрос представления чисел с плавающей точкой на конкретной машине или в конкретном окружении. Если хотите "железно" ограничить количество знаков после десятичной точки, можно настроить параметры pandas:

```
print(df.iloc[-1])
```

> 0    0.90065

```
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.3f}".format # 3 знака
print(df.iloc[-1])
```

> 0   0.901

Comment: Спасибо! А возможно ли как-то ограничить "не железно"?

Comment: А ой все я понял как сделать. Еще раз спасибо!